# How does where(property IN array) work in typeorm query builder?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, query-builder

I need to use query builder to filter an entity's ids by an array of ids.

This is the code:

```
await this._productRepo
.createQueryBuilder('Product')
.where('Product.id IN (:...ids)', { ids: [1, 2, 3, 4] })
```

This is the sql generated by this query:

```
SELECT [*FIELDS*] WHERE ( `Product`.`id` IN ? ) AND ( `Product`.`deletedAt` IS NULL )
```

This is a code example, that i found on the typeorm's doc, and i can't understand why there is a ? in the sql, instead of the list of ids.

I need query builder because the next step is to filter ids of a joined table, so i can't use Repository methods.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The query builder syntax above works.
The problem was in another part of my repo code.

If someone seems to have a similar issue, check all your code, the fact that getSql() report:

```
WHERE ( `field`.`property` IN ? )
```

is "normal", i think because typeorm's devs didn't want to print all array's values.